# Joomla insert Query not run

Tags: joomla-3.x, php

When I try to execute my `insert` query then, I get the following error:
[image]

Below is my code:

```
$fname = $posted['firstname'];
$email = $posted['email'];
$phone = $posted['phone'];
$productinfo = $posted['productinfo'];
$amount = $posted['amount'];
$address2 = $posted['address2'];
$country = $posted['country'];
$state = $posted['state'];
$city = $posted['city'];
$zipcode = $posted['zipcode'];
$date = date('y:m:d:h:m:s');

$query = "INSERT INTO `#__rays_donat` (`full_name`, `email`, `phone`, `production_info`, `amount`, `address`, `country`, `city`, `state`, `zipcode`, `form_submit_date`) VALUES ('$fname','$email','$phone', '$productinfo', '$amount', '$address2', '$country', '$city', '$state', '$zipcode', '$date')";

$db->setQuery( $query );

$db->query();
```

Please help me

Comment: The error message says that you are trying to insert into a table that doesn't exist. Check that the table name is correct and that you haven't made any spelling mistakes.

Comment: Flagging to close (and recommend deletion) because this question fails to provide enough detail to confidently provide a solution.  (We can only offer blind guesses as to what is wrong)  The OP has abandoned this question and this question has a low-likelihood of helping future researchers.

Answer (score 1):

Please try sticking to Joomla's coding methods and ensure your table name is correct:

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();

$query = $db->getQuery(true);

$columns = array('full_name', 'email', 'phone', 'production_info', 'amount', 'address', 'country', 'country', 'city', 'state', 'zipcode', 'form_submit_date');

$fname       = $db->quote($posted['firstname']);
$email       = $db->quote($posted['email']);
$phone       = $db->quote($posted['phone']);
$productinfo = $db->quote($posted['productinfo']);
$amount      = $db->quote($posted['amount']);
$address2    = $db->quote($posted['address2']);
$country     = $db->quote($posted['country']);
$state       = $db->quote($posted['state']);
$city        = $db->quote($posted['city']);
$zipcode     = $db->quote($posted['zipcode']);
$date        = $db->quote(date('y:m:d:h:m:s'));

$values = array($fname, $email, $phone, $productinfo, $amount, $address2, $country, $state, $city, $zipcode, $date);

$query->insert($db->quoteName('#__rays_donat'))
      ->columns($db->quoteName($columns))
      ->values(implode(',', $values));

$db->setQuery($query);
$db->execute();
```

Remember that `#__` is Joomla's generic table name prefix, so make sure you table name has the same prefix as other tables, for example:

- jos_users
- jos_content
- jos_extensions
- **jos_rays_donat**